# Does Martial study feat allow you to choose maneuvers earlier than a standard martial adept class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Martial Study feat states:

> **Select any maneuver** from the chosen discipline **for which you meet the prerequisite**. If you have martial adept levels, this maneuver becomes one of your maneuvers known. If you do not have martial adept levels, you can **use this maneuver** once per encounter as a martial adept with an initiator level equal to 1/2 your character level.

Now, there are very high level maneuvers that simply do not possess any prerequisites, therefore allowing a first level character to select shadow noose/shadow garotte/shadow blink/mountain tombstone strike/.... as his maneuver, as per the first sentence quoted above.

The problem is, I have yet to see a restriction limiting the use of maneuvers to those that match your initiator level -- the only restriction I've seen is the Maneuvers Known table, which limits the maneuvers you can select as a martial adept, and that is obviously a general rule overridden by the specifics of the feat above. Is there anything I missed, or is it really simply this broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Minimum Initiator Level is a prerequisite for learning and using a maneuver

It’s not listed in the statblock for maneuvers, but it’s consistently referred to as a prerequisite (the book is full of phrases like “you must meet all prerequisites for the maneuver, **including** the minimum initiator level.”) In fact, the Prerequisite definition given on page 44 specifically says

> #### PREREQUISITE
>
> **In addition to** meeting the class and level requirements before you can learn a maneuver,

(**emphasis** mine)

Martial Study requires that you meet prerequisites, so that means you must have the minimum initiator level.

Also, you use the maneuver as if you had the initiator level of a martial adept half your level... who couldn’t use a maneuver with a minimum Initiator Level even if he somehow knew it, because prerequisites are required for *use* as well as *learning*.

## So, final answer: No